# Rotate an image in openTK

Tags: c#, opengl, shader, fragment-shader, opentk

I want to rotate an image which is shown in my GLControl to 10 degree. For that I have rotated the bitmap using c# code and passed this rotated bitmap to opengl shader code. But the resulted image is seems like the rotated part is hiding/cut like below. Shall I need to do any changes on it's view port while rotating? or is it good to rotate the image in shader code itself?

```
     public void DrawImage(int image, int glcontrolWidth, int glcontrolHeight,Matrix4 **transformMatrix**)
    {
        GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 0, glcontrolWidth, glcontrolHeight));    
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, image);
        GL.Uniform1(positionLocation1, 0);

        RunShaders();
       
        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
        GL.PopMatrix();

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PopMatrix();

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);        

    }
    public void RunShaders()
    {
        GL.UseProgram(program);
        **GL.UniformMatrix4(transformLocation, false, ref transformMatrix);**
        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, vertices.Length / 3);
        ErrorCode ec = GL.GetError();
        if (ec != 0)
            System.Console.WriteLine(ec.ToString());
        Console.Read();
    }
    public void Init()
    {
        CreateShaders();
        CreateProgram();        
        InitBuffers();
    }
    public void CreateProgram()
    {
        program = GL.CreateProgram();
        GL.AttachShader(program, vertShader);
        GL.AttachShader(program, fragShader);
        GL.LinkProgram(program);       
    }
    public void InitBuffers()
    {
        buffer = GL.GenBuffer();
        positionLocation = GL.GetAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
        positionLocation1 = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexture");
        **transformLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "u_transform");**      
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(vertices.Length * sizeof(float)), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);

    }
    public void CreateShaders()
    {
        /***********Vert Shader********************/
        vertShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(vertShader, @"attribute vec3 a_position;
                                varying vec2 vTexCoord;
                           **uniform mat4 u_transform;**
                                void main() {
                                vTexCoord = (a_position.xy+1)/2 ;  
                                **gl_Position = u_transform * vec4(a_position, 1);**
                                }");
        GL.CompileShader(vertShader);

        /***********Frag Shader ****************/
        fragShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(fragShader, @"precision highp float;
  uniform sampler2D sTexture_2;varying vec2 vTexCoord; 
          void main ()
         {
     vec4 color = texture2D (sTexture_2, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y));
     gl_FragColor =color;

   }"); GL.CompileShader(fragShader);

    }
```

[image: Degree Ten]

Comment: *" But the resulted image is seems like the rotated part is hiding/cut"* - Yes of course. the image doesn't fit into the view. What do you expect? How should it look like? Do you want to scale the image? Why do you not just rotate the vertices on the GPU? Use model matrix to rotate the vertices, then it is easy to scale them, too.

Comment: I expect to see the fully rotated image in GLControl without losing any part of it.

Comment: Most likely `RotateTransform` clips the image. So you cant use this approach.

Comment: Can i rotate the image using shader code?

Comment: I've finished my answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not rotate the image, but rotate and scale the vertex coordinates.

Add a transformation matrix to the vertex shader:

```c
attribute vec3 a_position;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
uniform mat4 u_transform;

void main()
{
    vTexCoord = (a_position.xy+1)/2;
    gl_Position = u_transform * vec4(a_position, 1);
}
```

Get the location of the transformation matrix uniform (``u_transform´) (after the program is linked).

```cs
int transformLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "u_transform");
```

Compute the scale dependent on the angle:

```cs
double diagonal = Math.Sqrt(bmp.Width * bmp.Width + bmp.Height * bmp.Height);
double dia_angle1 = Math.Atan2(bmp.Height, bmp.Width) + angle * Math.PI / 180;
double dia_angle2 = Math.Atan2(bmp.Height, -bmp.Width) + angle * Math.PI / 180;
double rot_w = Math.Max(Math.Abs(diagonal * Math.Cos(dia_angle1)), Math.Abs(diagonal * Math.Cos(dia_angle2)));
double rot_h = Math.Max(Math.Abs(diagonal * Math.Sin(dia_angle1)), Math.Abs(diagonal * Math.Sin(dia_angle2)));
double scale = Math.Min(bmp.Width / rot_w, bmp.Height / rot_h);
```

Define a transformation matrix that scales and rotates the image taking into account the aspect ratio:

```cs
Matrix4 transformMatrix =
    Matrix4.CreateScale((float)scale) *
    Matrix4.CreateScale(this.Width, this.Height, 1.0f) *
    Matrix4.CreateRotationZ((float)(angle * Math.PI / 180)) *
    Matrix4.CreateScale(1.0f / this.Width, 1.0f / this.Height, 1.0f);
```

Set the matrix uniform, after the program is installed (after `GL.UseProgram`):

```cs
GL.UniformMatrix4(transformLocation, false, ref transformMatrix);
```

Comment: @user2431727 1. Yes it is the window size. 2. May bad `uniform u_transform;` -> `uniform mat4 u_transform;`

Comment: Is there any way to make the black color of resulted output (as shown in the image after rotation ) to transparent?

Comment: @user2431727 Do you mean you want to see the desktop through the window?

Comment: No I have mouse move event for GLControl. So when it moves over other UI controls like  over a picture box ,now that black color is hiding my picture box.

Comment: I have tried to change the clear color with alpha value to 0.1 . Seems like transparency is not changing.      GL.ClearColor(new Color4(255f, 0f, 0f, 0.1f));

Comment: @user2431727 Do you invoke `GL.Clear`? Color channels are in range [0.0, 1.0]

Comment: yes,               GL.ClearColor(new Color4(1f, 0f, 1f, 0.1f));
                    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);